# is it possible to use nuxt3 with quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, quasar

I'm very new to nuxt3 and want to know if i't possible to use it with quasar. specially that quasar has his own ssr system .
does anyone successfully created a project with these two frameworks ?

i tried to look if there is any open source projects with these two frameworks  but i couldn't find anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got that question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67604708/8816585

The TLDR is why would you mix both if they are doing the same thing. What does Quasar have over Nuxt (or the opposite)? Take one, it will allow you to do anything from the other afterward if needed.

Quasar is [already 147kB](https://bundlephobia.com/package/quasar@2.11.1), not sure that it's wise to add that to a Nuxt3 app anyway.

Comment: i want to use quasar only for the ui ( components ) i don't see why it's not wise the use them both

Comment: @CSharp-n it's like mixing PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can add material UI components to Nuxt without the need to use Quasar.

Comment: @CSharp-n Vuetify is great for Nuxt. Since the rest of Quasar (but the components) will not be used. No point into bringing the whole framework to Nuxt. Here you go: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#ssr

Answer (score 1):

There is a [module available](https://nuxt.com/modules/quasar) that let's you use Quasar UI with Nuxt 3.

I'm using it and it works great.

Comment: It's unofficial.

Comment: Yea your'e right, my bad!
Corrected my answer, thank you :)

Comment: I can testify that Nuxt-Quasar works perfectly! I'm migrating from Vuetify to Quasar and this plugin provides everything I could want

Comment: If its unofficial is there concern that it wont be updated and break as nuxt or quasar update not in sync?

Comment: Yep that risk always exists in the world of open source, however I believe that if it happens someone will fork it and make the necassary changes to make it work(maybe it could even be me or you, who knows!)